# R or python package to compute net reclassification improvement (NRI) for two different cutoffs

Tags: python, r, classification

There are different R packages available to compute the categorical NRI to compare two classification models (what is NRI? Check http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/SDA07.Kennedy.pdf). However, as I understand, almost all the available NRI calculating functions ask only for one cutoff value, which is used by both models to threshold their prediction scores (some of the packages are mentioned here: http://ncook.bwh.harvard.edu/r-code.html).

Is there a R or python function to compute the net reclassification improvement (NRI) based on two different cutoff values for each model?

NRI calculation example using the PredictABEL R library is available here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/195579_a3db37c9a51540e78f42e9ecde1f28f7.html

Any comments/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Doesn’t a fair comparison of models require that you select certain cumulative percentages of cases, like 40% best vs. 60% worst, and then compare the performance of both models to rank good and bad cases with fixed percentages i.e. using a single cut-off?

Comment: @Heikki: Still, I am trying to understand whether I need to use one or two cut-offs based on your comment. In my case, I have two different models (different features as well) which are trained on the same set of binary outcome values. Also, they have their own optimal cutoff value based on the maximum Youden index for stratification. If I have to use one cutoff to find the NRI, I do not know which one to pick.

Comment: Standard method is to draw ROC curve and compare the which model works better at a certain cut-off point in the ROC curve. A certain cut-of point could be x % of bads, good or total population. Younden index measures the distance of points in ROC curve with a fixed false positive rate, but similar distance could be calculated with a fixed true positive rate or total cumulative percentage of cases.